# Using pv with a Python script: monitoring progress when uploading to AWS Glacier using the boto glacier utility

Tags: unix, amazon-web-services, python, amazon-glacier

I am looking to use `boto`'s `glacier` command line tool to upload data to AWS Glacier. I'd like to monitor the progress of my upload.

Normally I use `pv` to monitor progress. I've perused the code of the `glacier` tool to see whether it reads data from standard input, but `glacier` is just a script around the `boto` library and it's not immediately discernable without digging further how data is opened. Either way, I doubt standard input is used. I suspect `argv` is used with a Python `with` block—the normal way to open and read a file with Python—and therefore piping data to the script from `pv` is a non-starter.

Does anyone have any thoughts on how I could watch the transfer rate and and progress using `boto`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the contents of

```
/proc/<PID>/io
```

where PID is the process id of whatever is doing the writing to glacier. In particular the values of `wchar` should indicate how far it's got.

Comment: interesting! thank you... will give that a whirl. i'm getting ~5MB/s from EC2 to Glacier with files that are 100MB-1GB. This file is 210GB. So, I'll have time to inspect its progress.

Comment: watch -n 0.5 less /proc/$PID/io — brilliant. thanks again